# C: 0x11 in Decimal

Tags: c, decimal, hex

Sorry about this basic question, but why `0x11` is `17` in decimal `(print(%d, 0x11)=17`?

I search information about the way to convert from hex to dec, but it doesn't talk about this sort of numbers.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal: 0x11 -> 1*16^0 + 1*16^1 = 17

Comment: maybe he's teaching himself :)

Comment: Just like 11 is 3 in binary.....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just like "11" in base ten means "1 ten" and "1 one", "11" in base 16 (i.e. hex) means "1 sixteen" and "1 one" - or 17 in base 10.

Answer (score 4):

`0x` at the start of a number means that the compiler will read it as hexadecimal. `0x11` = `1 * 16 + 1 = 17`

Answer (score 4):

0x11 = 1*16^1 + 1*16^0 = 17. (Like 17 = 1 * 10^1 + 7 * 10^0.)

Answer (score 2):

Hexadecimal counts with 16 digits, instead of 10. To account for the extra 6 digits, it uses letters `A` to `F`.

Counting from 0 in both base 16 and base 10:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,  A,  B,  C,  D,  E,  F, 10, 11 (base 16)
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 (base 10)
```

Also, to convert from base 16 to base 10:

11<sub>16</sub> = 1 * 16 + 1 = 17<sub>10</sub>

Answer (score 2):

```
0x11 =   1 * 16^1 (16)
       + 1 * 16^0 ( 1)
     -----------------
      0x11        (17)
```

Just like:

```
  17 =   1 * 10^1 (10)
       + 7 * 10^0 ( 7)
     -----------------
        17        (17)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe because 0x11 **IS** 17 in decimal?

Answer (score 0):

here is an easy way of seeing

128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1 = Decimal values of the...
    0   0   0   1 0 0 0 1 = Boolean switches that are ON or OFF

add them together 16 + 1 = 17

Comment: For a _very_ restricted definition of "easy"

Comment: This is what I figured out on my own when I was 8. In that sense it IS easy. Actually working out large numbers using this method is of course time consuming. This is just so that maybe the learner could visualise what is actually going on (i.e. internally everything is of course 1's and 0's)

Comment: I'm not saying it isn't useful. It just presupposes a lot of knowledge, which the question quite clearly states is not present.

Answer (score 0):

```
These answers are really confusing, I would suggest an easy way to understand. 

Hexadecimal base is 16

0x11 is 011 (simply remove x)


For 011 we have 3 digits right?
If we start from 0th position, these digits are:
 0th position(0 in 011),
 1st position (1 in 011)
 and 2nd position(again 1 in 011)


take positions in reverse order: 2,1,0

the calculation part

16^2 * value at first position(0th) = 16^2 * 0 = 0   
16^1 * value at second position (1st) = 16^1 * 1 = 16
16^0 * value at third position (2nd) = 16^0 * 1 = 1

adding all these answers will get 0 + 16 + 1 = 17
```

Comment: Hmm ... `0x11 is 011` ... not really. In C (the language this question is tagged with) integer constants with a leading zero are treated as **octal**, so `011` has the (decimal) value of 9.