# Why this line prints 17 and not 3?

Tags: c

Why this line prints 17 and not 3?

```
printf("%d" ,0x11);
```

Comment: `0x11` is hexadecimal, not binary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C: 0x11 in Decimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405033/c-0x11-in-decimal)

Comment: I think it's not duplicate. Yonatan knew that is hex, but didn't knew how hex works. user1462787 think that it's binary, and the right answer is simply "it's not birary. it's hex".

Answer (score 7):

`0x11` is *hexadecimal* (base 16) number, and `11` (*hexadecimal*) is equal to `17` *(decimal*).

Answer (score 4):

Because `0x` introduces a hexadecimal literal, not a binary one.